# Is it breaking the law if I break into on my own postbox without damaging it?

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm new to this stack and need some advice.

I'll explain my situation as best I can. I live in an apartment building, My S/O has the keys to our postbox(which resides inside the building  near the entrance). I need to get some forms that may or may not be there that are urgent and need to be dealt with asap. Both our names are on the lease and I have my drivers licence with my address on it as proof that I live in the building.

Here's the question;

if I were to break into our postbox (without damaging it) could there be any legal repercussions?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious crimes would be theft and criminal damage.

I think you are safe from theft (because the letters are for you).  However the law of criminal damage is drawn pretty widely (it certainly covers things that you might not ordinarily think of as "damage"), and it *might* cover this.

You might also find that somebody calls the police who arrest you first, and release you later.